# Anylogic sync. AGVs for Assembler

Tags: anylogic

I'm new on Anylogic and trying to build a Model for an Assembly Station. As for now my process is very simple and working well. The process:

1. Create Material in 3 Different Stations (Nodes) e.g. Production, warehouse and so on. The Material Agents in the different Stations are created in different Intervalls. For example Material for the Warehouse every 10 minutes, for the Production every 5 min.
2. Seize for each Station AGVs when Material is available and Transport Material to the Assembler
3. Assembler is Assembling
4. Final product leaving the Workstation.

So far so good. My following Problem is, that i would like to build something like a wait Function for all 3 AGVs before releasing the material. The Problem i'm seeking is, is that for example the AGVs that seize there material earlier are moving to the Assembler as wished, release their material and go back to their home location where the process starts over again. So is there any Option to say AGV1, AGV2, AGV3 wait in a Node till all 3 AGVs arrived at the Assembler and then release the material and move back to your home location to pick up new material or can i Set this Function in the Assembler for "on Enter"? I hope its not so complicated but still couldn't find a matching solution.

Current Process:

[image: View 1]

[image: View 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is there any Option to say AGV1, AGV2, AGV3 wait in a Node till all 3 AGVs arrived at the Assembler and then release the material and move back to your home location to pick up new material

Nope. You need to model this yourself explicitly

> or can i Set this Function in the Assembler for "on Enter"?

No again :). Simplest approach would be to model this with process-model library blocks such as `Wait`. A finished AGV agent is put in that and is pulled out to continue when the conditions are met. You then call `wait.free(myAGV)` to make it continue whatever it is supposed to be doing.,

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thank you for your fast Response. As you mentioned i added the wait block in my Model. So my process would be now:

Source --> seize --> move --> wait --> release.

I would like to put an extra Funktion for the agents in the wait block. So they should release on the same time. Therfore I tried something like this:

while(true) {
if(wait1.size()>0 &wait2.size()>0)wait.free(agent);
}
I think the code should be right but if I run my Model, i get the following error: "Unrentable Code". But i Cant find the error, May do you have a solution :)? thank you

Comment: best open a new issue with full details :)